# How to Create Generic Get Custom WebConfig Section Extension Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have the following code to get a custom Webconfig section

```
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration
(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + "/ExternalConfig");
        Sample1Section myHandler =
            (Sample1Section)config.GetSection("settings");
```

I want to convert it into Generic Extension Method so I won't repeat this same code for every custom section I create.

**Update 1**: I get Compile Time Error "Static Class cant have non-static Method"

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public T GetSection<T>(this string sectionName) where T : class
    {
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + "/ExternalConfig");
        return config.GetSection(sectionName) as T;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**: Fixed thanks to BrandonZeider :)

```
   public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T GetSection<T>(this string sectionName) where T : class
    {
        Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + "/ExternalConfig");
        return config.GetSection(sectionName) as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it would not bring you much: you'd still have to specify the generic type argument explicitly in each call, because the method won't have any way to infer it from its arguments.

Comment: thanks man, yes i know that, and i will, i just need the helper to accept any Custom Setting Type then i cast result, like what BrandonZeider suggested in his code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public T GetSection<T>(string sectionName) where T : class
{
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath + "/ExternalConfig");
    return config.GetSection(sectionName) as T;
}
```

Regarding your update, if your class is static, all members must also be static (mark the method static).

Comment: much appreciated man for fast reply, but i get Compile Time error "Static Class cant have non-static Method", please see update above

Comment: If your class is static, all members must also be static.